# What minifig and set is this shirt from?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, minifigure-identification

[image]

I’ve googled trying to figure out where this piece came from but I have no idea.

Please help me figure out what minifigure this shirt from? Also, if it’s from a larger set.

Answer (score 6):

This torso belongs to Deadshot as he appears in [76053 Gotham City Cycle Chase](https://brickset.com/sets/76053-1).

[image]